# How to set specific height at run time for Sliding layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I am building an app that uses this library:https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel to create a panel that slides on from the bottom of the screen when a user clicks an item in a listview.
However i dont want the slide up panel to take up the entire screen. I need there to be a gap at the top, between the panel and the action bar, of exactly 80dp.
I have tried everything i can think of (putting a spacer there with a transparant background, using layoutParams (gives error), etc). But nothing seems to work.

If someone could give me some suggestions as to what i could try next, i would much appreciate it.

The xml layouts are below.

Thanks for your time.

Corey

```
<com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:shadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:overlay="true">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabbutton"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:colour="@color/holo_red_light"
            app:drawable="@drawable/ic_content_new"

        />

    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/slideUpPanel"

        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >

            <fragment android:name="com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift.PlayFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_play"

                />
    </FrameLayout>

</com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I'm really interested in... :S

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping your `SlidingUpPanelLayout` in another layout, say `FrameLayout` and adding some good old paddingTop to the latter?

Comment: Hi, The problem with that though is that the slidingUpPanelLayout also contains the activities main view (which the panel slides up over). So then they would both get the padding, which isnt really what i want. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. Draw the background of the pane transparent and put a padding top, but first the library must be modified like it's written here:

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/4

Hope this helps somebody in the future :)